# Trouble Connecting to SQL Anywhere through ODBC

Tags: driver, database

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Anywhere database through an an ODBC connection on my Mac (running High Sierra).

I downloaded and installed the SQL Anywhere 17 Developer edition.  Installed it successfully.  I can launch it connect to my databases.  Yay!

Next, I downloaded and installed the [ODBC Administrator](http://www.odbcmanager.net/) I read about in multiple posts.  Installed it... seems to run as intended.

Next I added the SQL Anywhere 17 drivers to the ODBC Administrator (by following [these steps](http://dcx.sap.com/sqla170/en/html/812bd9006ce21014af83ad2e1d43df8c.html).

Then I tried adding a DSN (tested both User and System).  [The documentation on this](http://dcx.sap.com/sqla170/en/html/813057546ce21014940cfee1a017d30c.html) is a little lacking from SYBASE (specifically which parameters are "required").  Depending on what version of help you're looking at, the examples use different parameters.  In the end, I created parameters for the all the variables passed in the connection string (UserID, Password, Database File).  Sadly, there's no testing function in the ODBC Administrator to test a DSN.

So I return to SQL Anywhere and attempt to connect to a database via "Connect with an ODBC Data Source".   Here, I can "Test Connection".  And I consistently get the error: "[SAP][ODBC Driver Manager] Unable to load driver libodbc.dylib"

One thing I noticed is that when I added the SQL Anywhere 17 driver, I point (per the instructions)  to:  /Applications/SQLAnywhere17/System/lib64/dbodbc17.bundle.  Now I have no idea what a bundle file is.  Does it contain a 'bundle' of drivers?  No idea.  But unless this bundle file is supposed to contain libodbc.dylib (the file/driver reported as missing) then it's worth mentioning that file doesn't even exist on my Mac;  I've searched for it.

I'm relatively new to Mac OS (I've done this a million times in Windows).  Please, if anyone can help me with what I assume should be a fairly simple task, I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: Note the Sybase document says"Your Mac OS X system must not be version 10.6 or later." If that is correct are you on Snow Leopard.

Comment: Good question.  I must admit, I'm not used to reading "prerequisites" that require you are NOT on a version any newer than one released 13 years ago.  I most certainly am NOT on Snow Leopard.  Who the hell is still on Snow Leopard?!?!?  SQL Anywhere 17 came out in 2015... but requires OSX 10.4 to configure/create an ODBC connection?

Thank you for catching that.  I need to learn to read.

Still... I wonder if that's correct.  Seems odd to me.  I think 10.5 may have retired the built-in ODBC administrator, which is why you have to install the 3rd party one cited above.

Comment: You are thinking about it wrongly. Sybase stopped supporting OSX in 200x - possibly they never migrated to Intel. Look at the dates on Google results about Sybase and OSX. It might be worth asking Sybase directly via your support contract what is the state?

Comment: The possibility that I'm thinking about this wrongly is extremely possible/likely.  Still, I just recently downloaded SQL Anywhere 17 for Mac  (https://archive.sap.com/documents/docs/DOC-35857) and installed it on MacOS (High Sierra), and it runs great.  I can create, connect to, and query databases.  I just can't connect via ODBC.    Still, based on what you pointed out earlier, it still may be that an ODBC connection isn't supported.  I am continuing to research.  Thanks a bunch for your hlep.

Comment: @Mark , it actually looks like Sybase currently support SQL Anywhere, but not the ASE version, although they do not seem to disambiguate OSX vs macOS. These two documents show the support matrixes:

https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SQLANY/SAP+SQL+Anywhere+17.0+Components+by+Platforms#footnotes_3 & https://archive.sap.com/documents/docs/DOC-35654